# How to fix ghost commits on Github

Tags: github

I have a github account. Usually, For contribution, I create a new branch from `develop` branch of a repo and commit my changes and make a Pull Request. But, I saw that they are not being marked by User Name. When I see the commit details in `github` app, It says `ghost authored this commit`. When I see in github Web Interface, It says `<my-name> authored this commit` (But not my username).

What's this strange behavior? Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit**: It was my mistake. I didn't set my global config email and name. As mentioned in below accepted answer, I think GitHub tried and failed to get Username with associated email, which isn't there, And So, `ghost` user took over the authorship.

Comment: Did you try clicking on "ghost"?

Comment: Yes, it says as below in your answer. Hi I'm @ghost....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github uses the email address to match the commit with a Github account. If a matching account exists it uses the name from the account.

There exists an account called [ghost](https://github.com/ghost) which is described as

> Hi, I'm @ghost! I take the place of user accounts that have been deleted.

The Github app may think the commit is for a [deleted account](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/deleting-your-user-account).

> Deleting your user account removes all repositories, forks of private repositories, wikis, issues, pull requests, and pages owned by your account. Issues and pull requests you've created and comments you've made in repositories owned by other users will not be deleted - instead, ***they'll be associated with our Ghost user.***

Comment: Yeah, I saw some answers said that. But my account isn't a deleted one.

Comment: @AppajiChintimi Are you *sure* you've got the right email address on the commit? Double check with `git log --pretty=fuller`. Or maybe there's a bug in the Github app. Can you share a link to the repository and the commits in question?

Comment: I didn't set my name and email in git global config. (This)[https://github.com/intelowlproject/IntelOwl/pull/246/commits] is my PR

Comment: @AppajiChintimi Weird. It shouldn't have assigned you to ghost. [It Works For Me™](https://pasteboard.co/JBXxL05.png). Must have been a Github Desktop glitch. Glad you got it sorted.